# JTable : how to change the jtable apparance

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i need to change my jtable appearance .

i have these data  :

1. image image.
2. title String.
3. date String .
4. description String.
5. auteur String .

img , title , date ,description ,auteur.
my question is :
is that possible that i can show in every row these data as twitter feed appearance . 
i want to show all these data in the same cell with a sample .

thanks every one .

Comment: You should create your own `TableCellRenderer`. There is many tutorials on the web...

Comment: and TableCellRenderer has paramater for row and column, use those two coordinates for define the getColumnClass

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `JList` (or a `JTable`, but with only one cell per row, a `JList` seems to be more appropriate) with a custom cell renderer.

Create your data class

```
public class MyData {
  // image, title, date, description and author
}
```

Create your cell renderer

```
class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<MyData> {

     public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
       JList<?> list,           // the list
       MyData value,            // value to display
       int index,               // cell index
       boolean isSelected,      // is the cell selected
       boolean cellHasFocus)    // does the cell have focus
     {
         // tune your component in the way you want, for example
         this.setText(value.getTitle());
         // return the component to draw for this cell
         return this; 
     }
 }
```

Of course, your cell renderer can extends another component like `JPanel`.
Finally, instantiate a `JList` and set your custom renderer

```
JList<MyData> list = new JList<>();
list.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```

Comment: i create the class data :
public class Info {
 private int id_info;
 private String titre;
 private String description;
 private String lien;
 private String auteur;
 private String pub_date;
 private String guid;
 private String thumbnail_url;
        private Image myImage;
}
how it should be used for you're exemple

Comment: @user3612862 In my example, you can replace `MyData` by your class `Info`.  More informations about cell renderer are available in the [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)